# How to change multiple elements innerHTML using setinterval?

Tags: javascript, django, vue.js

I'm working on certain app and I need to create kind of count down for each element. Unfortunately when I', passing the element to my function it does not work. Neverthless if I change the function a bit and just replace the element's innerHTML out of the setInterval it starts working. I'm totally out of any idea now. Appreciate for help :) const timeout is the element.

```
const json_content = json_reader(reserved)
for(x=0;x<json_content["key"].length;x++){
    var tds = document.querySelectorAll(".display_content table td")
    for(let td of tds){
        new Vue({
        delimiters: ['[[', ']]'],
        el:td,
        data: { 
            display: "test",
            seats_number: "0",
        },
        methods:{
            test(){
                console.log("elo")
            }
        },
        created: ()=>{
                const td_date = td.innerText
                if(td_date.includes(json_content["key"][x])){
                    const td_hour = td.nextElementSibling
                    const json_hour = json_content["value"][x]["times"]
                    if(Object.keys(json_hour).includes(td_hour.innerText)){
                        const seats = json_content["value"][x]["times"][td_hour.innerText]
                        const td_seat = td_hour.nextElementSibling
                        const timeout = td_seat.nextElementSibling
                        const seats_array = []
                        seats.forEach(element => {
                            const seat_json = json_reader(element)
                            seats_array.push(seat_json["key"]+":"+seat_json["value"])
                        });
                        this.seats_number = seats.length
                        td_seat.innerHTML = "<span onclick='display_seats(this.nextSibling)'>"+[[this.seats_number]]+"</span>"+"<span class='seats' value='"+seats_array+"'></span>"
                        counter(timeout)
                    } 
                }   
            }
        })
    }
}
```

and counter function:

```
function counter(element){
    var t = 10
    setInterval(()=>{
        element.innerHTML = String(t)
        t -= 1
    },1000)
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Not sure, where are you calling the counter function

```html
<input type="number" id="inp">
<div id="counter"></div>
<script>
let input = document.getElementById('inp')
let counter = document.getElementById('counter')

let handleInput = e => {
 let num = Number(e.target.value)
 let _counter = num - 1
 let timer = setInterval(_ => {
 if(!_counter)
   clearInterval(timer)
  counter.innerText =  _counter
  _counter--
 }, 1000)
}
input.addEventListener('input', handleInput)
</script>
```

But something like above should work. You can input numbers from 1-9 to test.

2. Another thing is, check if the element you are passing is actually the element you aare looking for. You might want to `console.log(element)` and check.
3. Directly updating dome is not a very good idea. You can access the dom via `ref` or just use a variable initialized in `data()` and just update the variable every second, rest will be taken care of by vue

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    timer: 20
  },
  mounted() {
 setInterval(()=> this.timer--, 1000)
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  {{timer}}
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. Unfortunately the variable under data remains the same. I tested it on console.log and it returned the different value but just in console.

Comment: Is data variable very nested?

Comment: new Vue module is under loop so each iteration has own vue module and individual data variable.

Comment: Not sure, why is that so, but if that's the use case, you can go with 1st approach keeping a `counter` variable outside of the loop.

Comment: Well it must be in the loop because the loop iterates over all of the td nth-child(1) and inside the loop I declare the siblings. Counter function needs argument which is the element (nth-child(4) in this case) and then replaces the innerText basing on count down